# Getting Windows 7 onto a device

Tags: windows-7, windows, license, deployment

We are a small company that make a data logging device plus a desktop application that accesses and analyses the data.  The device contains a miniITX atom board and the software is Windows 7 professional 32-bit running our VB.NET data logging program as a Windows service.

What is the best way to deploy Windows 7 to these devices as we make them?

I looked at using Windows Embedded, even bought a book on it, but found it way too complicated to build the image and buy licenses in small volumes.  So then I thought Windows 7 OEM would be the way to go.  The problem here is that you have to buy physical DVDs for each copy and pass it and the license on to the end user.  Our customers just want a box that works, not to enter into a license agreement with microsoft, plus there is no VDU or keyboard on the device to accept a license agreement etc.  We need to just blow an image on to the box, give MS their money, and move on.

We make about one device a week.  What are my options?  I am beginning to think about porting our program to Linux as all these issues seem to go away by using Debian as the OS.

Thanks

Comment: `I am beginning to think about porting our program to Linux as all these issues seem to go away by using Debian as the OS.` - So why don't you? Seems like this will solve your problem

Comment: If `Windows Embedded` was to complicated the other solutions are not simple either.

Comment: Have you called MS' licensing dept. for some advice? Or perhaps contact a local volume license reseller.

Comment: Dave Rook - Because porting our program to linux is not trivial.  I would probably use Python and have to properly learn that language first!  Techie007 - that is my next stop.

Comment: "Our customers just want a box that works, not to enter into a license agreement with microsoft" If you don't want them to enter into a license agreement with MS, you need to not ship it with Microsoft software.

Comment: If you sysprep an imagine of windows on the hard drive the license key can be included in the sysprep.ini.  Clone the hard drive with clonezilla or whatever.  After cloning you can connect the hard drive to a PC and change the license key in the sysprep.ini file and put in back in the machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the OS with MDT 2012 and USB, but yes; if you're turning around and selling these systems you'll have to use OEM licensing.